# Upload local files to google cloud storage bucket using SSIS

Tags: google-cloud-storage, ssis-2012

I have a requirement where I need to upload the files to google cloud storage( He owns and maintain it completely) bucket.

This google cloud storage bucket is created by my client.

I am new to google cloud and have experience on Amazon S3. I have SSIS running on a server to load the transactional data to flat files.

I created a sample account for google cloud and installed Google SDK. I am able to upload files manually through gsutil.

my questions are

1. what should I propose my client to share the credentials ?
2. How can i connect to google cloud storage with provided credentials independently ?
3. How can I push the files to the google cloud storage with above 2 steps.

any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try this: http://www.cdata.com/drivers/google/ssis/

Answer (score 1):

> 1. what should I propose my client to share the credentials ?

Give the customer the name of your existing Google account (or create a new one). Ask them to grant that account the relevant permissions. If the bucket is enough, ask to be made an OWNER of the bucket. Or, ask to be added to the list of owners of the project.

> 2. How can i connect to google cloud storage with provided credentials independently ?

You'll be using your own account's credentials.

> 3. How can I push the files to the google cloud storage with above 2 steps.

Manually, with gsutil, it's pretty easy. You'll just authenticate as yourself. If you want to set up an automated process, you'll want to create a "service account" that represents that job. The service account with come with a private key that it will use to authenticate itself. Gsutil can act as a service account, if you want to set up a cron job.

I am unfamiliar with the exporting abilities of SSIS, so I can't help you with that part.

Answer (score 1):

If you are able to manually upload the file using gsutil, you can use the same command, put it in a batch file and run it through SSIS.

Include "Execute Process Task" in SSIS and provide the batch file path as the executable. You should be able to get it running on your system.

However, if you want to do the same thing in production, it's better to have a service account. This account will be set as default account in production.